# Simplest way to assign version numbers to static files in django to avoid caching?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-templates

I want to introduce versioning on static files so that the browser doesn't cache them since I will be putting out changes quite often. So currently in my `index.html`, I call my two files `index.css` and `index.js` like so

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}"></script>
```

Now I want to introduce versioning such that the browser is forced to fetch the latest files when I update the files with some changes. Offcourse this doesn't mean it should always fetch new files but when I ask it to.

So to do that I need to register a template tag. So I make a folder called `templatetags` and keep it in the same level where my `models.py` and `urls.py` are. (Keeping it elsewhere Django throws error). I name the file as `assign_version.py`. This is the content inside the file

```
import time
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def static_version():
        print("version changed!!")
        version = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        return version
```

The `templatetags` folder looks like

```
assign_version.py  assign_version.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
```

Now I change my `index.html` to refer to these two tags like so

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load staticfiles %} {% load assign_version %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}?v={{ static_version }}"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}?v={{ static_version }}"></script>
```

Then I restart my server. But nothing happens. I do not see the `print` that I have put to confirm whether this template is being called on restart. Also changing `js` or `css` and restarting doesn't seem to force the browser to fetch new files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an ```__init__.py``` in you templatetags folder as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)?

Comment: @Chris Yes I do. Edited the question..

Comment: Just spotted your line ```version = int(round(time.time() * 1000)``` is missing a ```)``` at the end

Comment: And to use template tags you must use ```{% static_version %}``` and not ```{{ static_version }}```

Comment: @Chris Good observation but I actually pasted it wrong here. My code in my project has correct syntax. Fixed it in the question. (In reference to version syntax in .py file you mentioned)

Comment: @Chris ok let me try that..

Comment: @Chris You are right. Now on changing the tag syntax, I see the version number getting changed on refresh. But should't that only happen when I restart the server. It seems everytime I refresh the page, the version number changes.

Comment: Why do you expect the value to only change on server restart? Every time django creates the html from the template the tag is used.

Comment: @Chris Oh I see. This would mean none of the users who use my site would be able to cache it. I wanted a behaviour where the version changes only when I want it to not on a mere refresh. Any idea how can I do that? Anyways you may post your answer highlighting the typo and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please be aware that templatetags are used with `{% your_tag %}` and not with `{{ your_tag }}`. So replace `{{ static_version }}` with {% static_version %} in your template.

However, as the tag is used every time django generates the html page from your template a new "version" is put into your page every time the page is loaded. So you will probably not achieve waht you are intending.

If you want to save the time every time the server is restarted an approach I can think of is using the `AppConfig` in your `apps.py`. It is called whan the app is reloaded. So maybe something like this:

In your `assing_version.py` add the variable "version" as a "global" variable and use this as your version:

```
#assign_version.py

import time
from django import template

register = template.Library()

version = 0

@register.simple_tag
def static_version():
    print("version changed!!")

    return version
```

Set the version in your apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

import time

from . templatetags import assign_version

class YourappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourapp'

    def ready(self):
        assign_version.version = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

For this to work you need to load your app in `settings.py` with "yourapp.apps.YourappConfig" and not just with "yourapp".

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManifestStaticFilesStorage to achieve this.

From the docs:.

> A subclass of the StaticFilesStorage storage backend which stores the file names it handles by appending the MD5 hash of the file’s content to the filename. For example, the file css/styles.css would also be saved as css/styles.55e7cbb9ba48.css.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage